# Горизонтальный скролл убрать

Tags: html, css, scss, прокрутка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Господа, как убрать горизонтальный скролл? Повернул svg, есть пос. абсолют, и меньший z-index, но из-за этого угла появляется скролл. Как можно решить ситуацию?

Comment: погуглите, что такое overflow

Comment: Не думаю что кому то будет приятно переписывать код вручную. Нельзя было отправить код, а не фотографию ?

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: hidden; скроет все элементы выходящие за блок
```